# Confusion with showing that $HN/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Suppose $G$ is a group, $H \le G, $ and $N \triangleleft G$.

Show that
$$HN/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$$
Well, I know there was a similar question on math.stackexchange and I know there is a solution by first isomorphism theorem.

But I want to solve it using another method (by definitions).

I'll assume that we know that $HN$ is a subgroup in $G$ and that $N$ is a normal subgroup in $HN$ (since it is normal in $G$).

Firstly, using the definition of quotient:
$$HN/N=\{hnN\mid n\in N, h \in H\}$$
Since $nN=N$ we can say that
$$
HN/N=\{hN\mid h \in H\}
$$

But then it comes that $HN/N = H/N$ and not $HN/N=H/(N \cap H)$. Well, actually $H/N$ may not be even a group. But it seems all steps were right. Where is a bug here?

Comment: Note that $N$ is not necessary a subset of $H$, so $H/N$ don't have sense in general.

Comment: Yep, you're definitely right. But the problem here is slightly different: by $H/N$ I mean the set(not quotient group)  $\{hN | h \in H\}$. And thing is, our $HN/N$ is equal to this set $\{hN | h \in H\}$ and not to the $\{h(N\cap H)| h \in H\}$ as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should really not write $H/N$, because this notation assumes that $N\subseteq H$, and that is not the case here. You can certainly look at cosets of $N$ represented by elements of $H$.

But now let's look more carefully at what you have. Just because you have $h\neq h'$, it does not follow that $hN\neq h'N$, right? So what cosets do you *really* have?

Well, $hN = h'N$ if and only if $h'^{-1}h\in N$. But certainly $h'^{-1}h\in H$, so you will in fact have $hN=h'N$ if and only if $h'^{-1}h\in H\cap N$.

That means that in fact you don't have as many cosets as there are elements of $H$: you really just have as many cosets as you have cosets of $H\cap N$ in $H$. Hmm.... where did we see a connection between those cosets again?

Second... you say "Well, $H/N$ may not even be a group"... actually, remember that "$H/N$" is a misnomer. It's **really** $HN/N$, and that is *definitely* a group, because it is a subgroup of $G/N$. If you define the operation on your collection of representatives, all of the form $hN$ with $h\in H$, by
$$(h_1N)(h_2N) = (h_1h_2)N$$
you will find that this is in fact a well-defined operation that gives a group. Just remember that you have multiple names for each element!

In fact, we just have one coset of $N$ represented by an element of $H$ for each coset of $H\cap N$ in $H$. It would be interesting to see whether, if we choose representatives for the cosets of $H\cap N$ in $H$ and use *them* and them alone, we get the same definition of the operation...

Note that the assertion is that you have an *isomorphism*, not an **equality**. So the fact that the set $\{hN\mid h\in H\}$ is not literally equal to the set $\{h(N\cap H)\mid h\in H\}$ is not an obstacle for there to be an isomorphism between them. You need a bijection between the two sets that respects the operations defined on them, of course, but you don't need an actual equality of underlying sets.